# Doctrine does not create a new table from an - already exist - entity class?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity defined as:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\myBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Acme\CoreBundle\Model\Message;

/**
 * Facebook Post
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * ORM\Table(name="acme_facebookPost")
 * ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\FacebookBundle\Entity\FacebookPostRepository")
 */
class FacebookPost extends Message
{
  // entity properties
}
```

This entity class was created somewhere else in my project and I just moved it here.
When I run following commands to generate the entity and update my tables, it runs without error but, I can not see acme_facebookPost table in my database.

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeFacebookBundle:FacebookPost

Generating entity "Acme\FacebookBundle\Entity\FacebookPost"
  > backing up FacebookPost.php to FacebookPost.php~
  > generating Acme\FacebookBundle\Entity\FacebookPost
```

and then:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

P.S.
I need to add that I'm using annotation and there is no metadata anywhere inside my bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to add `@` before `ORM\Entity(...` and `ORM\Table(..` hence your class is not identified as an entity